# variable variables in BASH

Tags: bash, variables

I would like to ask some help regarding variable variables in bash. I've read a few articles about it, but in my case I don't know how to do it. Let see my problem:

The array contains other arrays' names and I want to print the values of these arrays. In inner for I need variable variables.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
declare -a array=(dir1 dir2 dir3)
declare -a dir1=(1 2 3)
declare -a dir2=(a b c)
declare -a dir3=(9 8 7)

for elem1 in "${array[@]}"
do
  for elem2 in "${variableVariable[@]}"
  do
    echo "$elem1 : $elem2"
  done
done
```

The output should be something like this

```
dir1 : 1
dir1 : 2
dir1 : 3
dir2 : a
dir2 : b
dir2 : c
dir3 : 9
dir3 : 8
dir3 : 7
```

Comment: Don't use variable variables in this case. Use [associative arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494178/how-to-define-hash-tables-in-bash).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lookup shell variables by name, indirectly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694196/lookup-shell-variables-by-name-indirectly)

Comment: Thanks Guys! The links are useful!

Comment: @tripleee It's similar to that question, but there's some extra work you have to do to deal with `[@]` when indirecting. It took me a while to figure it out.

Comment: Mine problem is the how to deal with `[@]` part of the script. Can you help me?

Answer (score 7):

This can be done using bash's *indirect variable* feature.

```
for elem1 in "${array[@]}"
do
  elems=$elem1'[@]'
  for elem2 in "${!elems}"
  do
    echo "$elem1 : $elem2"
  done
done
```

Note that this is a bash extension, it's not portable to other shells.

Comment: I'll take a look at it. I would like to run my script in git shell on windows.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the solution. I had to use eval because I was not able to deal with the other syntax, I mean the composition of the `${!variable}` and the `${variable[@]}`.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
declare -a array=(dir1 dir2 dir3)
declare -a dir1=(1 2 3)
declare -a dir2=(a b c)
declare -a dir3=(9 8 7)

for elem1 in "${array[@]}"
do
  for elem2 in `eval echo \$\{$elem1\[@\]\}"`
  do
    echo "$elem1 : $elem2"
  done
done
```