# bash $var_$1 does not work on sed

Tags: bash, function, variables, sed

I have this situation:

here is some file.conf :

```
1stRecord value
2ndRecord value
3rdRecord value
```

I need to replace value for some record. Here is my script:

```
    correct_1stRecord='new1stValue'
    correct_2ndRecord='new2ndValue'
    correct_3rdRecord='new3rdValue'
    function correct_record() {
     sed -i 's/^$1 $(cat file.conf | grep -e "^$1" | awk '{print $2}')/$1 $correct_$1/" file.conf
    }
correct_record 3rdRecord
```

when I run it the $correct_$1 did not switch to $correct_3rdRecord and as a result I have this record:

```
3rdRecord 3rdRecord
```

When I expect it to be:

```
3rdRecord new3rdValue
```

I was trying to modify the second part of the sed expression to /$1 $(correct_$1) byt then it was showing that command correct_3rdRecord does not exist, however (1) it is not a command but variable, (2) I did declare it above.

Comment: Variables aren't expanded inside single quotes, but what are you really trying to do?  There's almost never going to be a reason to you use `cat`, `sed`, `grep`, and `awk` all at the same time.  I think your quoting got a little mixed up when creating the question.  If you're trying to use `$correct_$1` to be the name of a variable you want to expand, you should check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694196/lookup-shell-variables-by-name-indirectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks a lot for the sugestion.
I did this this way:

```
function go() {
  correct_userlogin='niza'
  correct_useraddress='theCenter'
  old_value=$(cat dwa | grep -e "^$1"| awk '{print $2}')
  eval $(echo correct_var='$'"correct_$1")
  echo $correct_var
  sed -i "s/^$1 $old_value/$1 $correct_var/" dwa
}
go userlogin
go useraddress
```

As a result I got:
The records befoure:

```
userlogin johny
useraddress out
```

The records after:

```
userlogin niza
useraddress theCenter
```

works pretty well now.
thanks a lot