# Writing custom variable into quoted variable in Bash

Tags: bash, variables, quote

How can a bash variable be written into a quoted variable ?
For example;

x = '$RES'

when i echo this one, it returns $RES, but the code below ends with 1 (error)

```
test "$x" = "$RES" ; echo $?;
```

the command above should return 0 when it succeeds. What is wrong with that ?

thanks for a rapid reply,

---

Edit:

```
    # this script is running with the rights of other user.(sudo)
    # Usage: ./test.sh [password]

    RES=$(cat .secret) # i have no read access right.

    if [ ! -v "$1" ]; then
       echo "Bad Luck! You are evil.."
       exit 1
    fi


    if test "$1" = "$RES" ; then
       echo "OK : $RES"
    else
       echo "Repeat it.."
    fi
```

---

```
export x=RES

export RES=RES # i tried it in anyway like RES='$RES' and so on.

./test.sh $x
```

when i call a bash script with a parameter for example x and declare it by x=$RES it still does not bypass the equality.

Comment: `Edit:` Please one question per question. Please do not create follow up questions.

Comment: @jam : Are you sure that `test.sh` and the calling process access the same variable `RES`? Perhaps you forgot to export it?

Comment: As i posted and edited the question, the code block might have ignored the important part of it. I edited above. RES="secret" added line.

Comment: Or better RES=$(cat .secret) i have no read access.

Comment: Is there any way to get out of this cage to bypass this task ? If not, then i am sure it is secured correctly. Thanks for struggling on this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as a *quoted variable*.

In your command

```
test "$x" = "$RES"
```

`x` in your example has the value `$RES` (i.e. consists of 4 characters).

On the right-hand side, you are using Double quotes, which interpolate the value of the variable (in this case, the variable `RES`). You did not say what value `RES` contains, but unless you explicitly have set

```
RES='$RES'
```

they will compare to not-equal. To compare to equality, you have to compare `x` to the **string** *$RES* and not to the content of the variable `RES`. You can do this either with

```
test $x = '$RES' # single quotes prevent interpolation
```

or

```
test $x = \$RES # backslash escapes interpolation
```

Comment: Hi, i edited the post at the beginning... It was an example what i meant with the bypass. Exactly what i wanted to know is how to pass a variable as parameter and bypass the equality. ./test.sh $RES; then $1 should be $RES. But it still does not work.

Comment: "indirect variable reference" was helpful.

Comment: The main thing is how to make $1 to $RES, so "$1"="$RES" equality can be bypassed without knowing the inside of RES variable.

Comment: And by the way, i am not privileged enough to change the code, because of the level for this homework, all i can speculate is about dealing with the $x value.

Comment: @jam : There is no indirect variable reference going on in this example.

Comment: @jam : If you want the test `"$1" = "$RES"` to succeed, the parameter must contain the exact content of the variable `RES`. Assuming that RES is an environment variable in the calling process, you would simply pass `"$RES"` as parameter. In this case, to save yourself headache, I suggest to do a `set -u`, to catch cases where `RES` is not set.

Answer (score 1):

To copy a value from one variable to another one, use normal assignment:

```
x=$RES
test "$x" = "$RES" && echo Same
```

Double quotes expand variables, so `"$RES"` corresponds to the content of the variable `$RES`. If it doesn't contain the string `$RES`, the values are not equal.

Single quotes don't expand variables:

```
test "$x" = '$RES'
```

Or, backslash the dollar sign:

```
test "$x" = \$RES
test "$x" = "\$RES"
```

Comment: Hi choroba, i mean how can i make $x to $RES, so that i am able to pass the task.. thx

Comment: .. and in this case i am able to change only the x variable not RES...

Comment: @jam: I don't understand. What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: To assign the value from $RES to $x, just `x=$RES`.

Comment: i want to bypass $RES without having knowledge of what is inside.

Comment: What do you mean by "bypass"?

Comment: i mean with bypass that it is a challenge homework, i developed. Thanks for your reply. I will try it harder. For now it is okay.

Comment: @jam Are you trying to do an [indirect variable reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694196/lookup-shell-variables-by-name-indirectly)?

Comment: I am not interested in the value of RES. I just want to bypass the equality. I want to pass the RES variable to x as parameter and make the code to see that there is already the variable RES and not to claim that there is something wrong with that.